# How to obtain document that was just upserted in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the following command, where `foos` is a collection, I "upsert" a new item:

```
foos.update(criteria, 
  { $set: fooUpdate }, 
  { w: 1, upsert: true }, 
  function(err, upsertedFoo) {
    /* upsertedFoo is actually just count of updated/ inserted rows */
}
```

I would like to obtain the new document that was just created (if it was an update), or the existing document that was modified (if it was updated). If this is not possible, the `_id` of it will also suffice.

How can I get this?

NOTE: I am using the standard [`mongodb`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) package.

Comment: @wizard findAndModify works with upsert?

Answer (score 0):

The `update` function's callback will give you the updated document. For example:

```
foo.update(conditions, document, options, function(err, result) {
  if (err)
   throw new Error(err);
  console.dir(result);
}
```

Comment: The thing is, that I am doing an upsert, which isn't quite the same as an update.

Answer (score 0):

If you use findAndModify with `new:true` you will get updated or new objects as result, it works with upsert.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#return-new-document

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify):

```
// Simple findAndModify command performing an upsert and returning the new document
// executing the command safely
collection.findAndModify({d:1}, [['b', 1]],
  {d:1, f:1}, {new:true, upsert:true, w:1}, function(err, doc) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, doc.d);
    assert.equal(1, doc.f);
     db.close();
})
```

This 'new' option seems to be the key:

**new** *{Boolean, default:false}*

set to true if you want to return the modified object rather than the original. Ignored for remove.

Hope this helps